# Using variables as table names in R and MySQL

Tags: r, select, rmysql

how do I get a MySQL SELECT statement that takes a variable as table name.

As an example:

```
a = "table1"
b = "table2"
```

and so on...

Now I want to integrate these variables into the SELECT statement:

```
dbSendQuery(mydb, "select * from a")
```

I tried it with different comma variations but unfortunately without success. I also tried the percentage sign.

Can anyone tell me how I can solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dbSendQuery(mydb, sprintf("select * from %s",a))
```

`sprintf` should help in this case. For more info on how this works try `?sprintf`